# select text from span in selenium java enviroment , when its not a drop box

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

so I want to select the text of span in selenium java, as it is not a normal drop-down box, I would have done it easily, I am using XPath I am able to open that drop-down box (where we select different sizes of shirt) type but no able to select text from it, I am sharing website link and also sharing my code
https://www.ounass.ae/shop-emporio-armani-camouflage-print-t-shirt-in-mercerised-cotton-for-men-215380566_20.html

my Code,

```
package First_Test;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WindowType;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ISelect;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

    public class Practice_First {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            
            //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Driver/chromedriver.exe");
    
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            
            
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            
            driver.get("https://www.ounass.ae/");
    
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
            Thread.sleep(3000);
    
                         String originalWindow= driver.getWindowHandle();
    
                     Thread.sleep(5000);
        
                       driver.findElement(By.id("wzrk-cancel")).click();      
                       
                 // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='wzrk-cancel']")).click();
                  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/men']//div[@class='Gender-centralize']//span[@class='Gender-CTA'][normalize-space()='Shop Now']")).click();
    
                  Thread.sleep(2000);
                 //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='shop-emporio-armani-camouflage-print-t-shirt-in-mercerised-cotton-for-men-215380566_20.html']")).click();
                  // driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title=\"Camouflage Print T-shirt in Mercerised Cotton\"]")).click();
                  
                  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='675 AED']")).click();
    
                  Thread.sleep(3000);
    
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Blue']")).click();
    
                 Thread.sleep(2000);
                 
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Select-control']")).click();
    
               Thread.sleep(1000);
    
               //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Select Dropdown SizeSelection-options 
             
                Thread.sleep(1000); */      
            //driver.close();
                
        }   
    }
```

My html code :

```
<div class="Select Dropdown SizeSelection-options SizeSelection-fixedSize has-value Select--single" xpath="1">
    
    <input name="sizeCode" type="hidden" value="75">
    
    <div class="Select-control">
    
    <div class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-sizeCode--value">
    
    <div class="Select-value">
    <span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-sizeCode--value-item">M</span>
    </div>
    
    <div aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-activedescendant="react-select-sizeCode--value" aria-disabled="false" class="Select-input" role="combobox" style="border:0;width:1px;display:inline-block" tabindex="0">
    </div>
    
    </div>

    <span class="Select-arrow-zone"><svg width="12" height="7" viewBox="0 0 20 10" class="svg">
    
    <path d="M0 0l10 10L20 0" stroke="#2d2d2d" class="svg-stroke">
    </path>
    
    
</svg>
    
    

</span>
    
    

</div>
    
   

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below xPath for clicking on dropdown Item.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[text()='XS']").Click();
```

Comment: Thanx alot for the answer its working finally , please can you explain me this part briefly
//*[text()='XS']"

Comment: If it is working, can you please mark it as Solved. When you open the dropdown you can select items now we have to Select any of the Item from dropdown. Currently we dont know the tag name of the xpath hence we have used //* which means it can accept any tag name and for dropdown we have text hence we have set as [text()='XS']